# I am getting resourse id#5

Tags: php, mysql

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00')");
            if(!$results)
            {
            echo mysql_error();

            }
            else
            {
                echo $resulta;
            }
```

when i am running this query i am getting Resource id #5

Comment: You need to fetch the result for display.

Comment: try `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($resulta));` instead of `echo $resulta;`. You should probably learn PHP from a good book/tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00')");
    if (!$results) {
        echo mysql_error();
    } else {
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
        var_dump($data); //check all the data that is returned
    }
```

**Side Note**: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. `mysql_*` is deprecated. Recommend you use pdo

Comment: I am getting this==>

array(1) { ["TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00')"]=> string(5) "79259" }
I need time in seconds(79259) from resultant output

Comment: yeah that's your desired result. use `print_r($data)` for a clearer picture. @veerendrareddy

Answer (score 2):

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00')");
       while($data=mysql_fetch_row($results)){

       //your answer

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this way also

```
$results=("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00')");
$re = mysql_query($results) or die("wrong query".mysql_error());
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array($re))
  { 
 //your code here
  }
```

and yes as mention above your code is vulnerable to sql injection.